# Creating a new element with specific id no. using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a new element with specific id names every time button is clicked.

Basically, I am creating a form with the following inputs:

```
                <h2>Ownership Structure</h2>
                <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                  <input type="text" id="ownerName1" class="form-control" />
                  <label class="form-label" for="typeText"
                    >Name of Owner(s)/Major Shareholders:</label
                  >
                </div>
                <button
                  onclick="newShareholder()"
                  type="button"
                  class="mb-2 btn btn-primary btn-sm ripple-surface"
                >
                  Add Shareholders
                </button>
```

Here is my trial which I am stuck with so far:

```
              <script>
                function newShareholder() {
                  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                  btn.innerHTML = " Add Shareholders";
                  document.body.appendChild(btn);
                }
              </script>
```

My objective is to create a new div with input and label and the same class every time the button is clicked but in the id instead of `ownerName1` to be `ownerName2` and if clicked one more time to be `ownerName3` and so on.

I also want to position the duplicated elements about the `Add Shareholders` every time a new one is created.

Comment: For starters I suggest you create some more conteriziation structure so you aren't inserting to body each time and insert into a container. Beyond that you shown you know how to create a button so what is stopping you creating input and div? Hint: Create the div and append to that then insert div in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Store the `id` index in a variable and increment it every time you append a new button:

```js
var buttons = 1;

function newShareholder() {
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.innerHTML = " Add Shareholders";
  btn.id = "ownerName" + buttons;
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  buttons++;
}
```

```html
<h2>Ownership Structure</h2>
<div class="form-outline mb-4">
  <input type="text" id="ownerName1" class="form-control" />
  <label class="form-label" for="typeText">Name of Owner(s)/Major Shareholders:</label>
</div>
<button onclick="newShareholder()" type="button" class="mb-2 btn btn-primary btn-sm ripple-surface">Add Shareholders</button>
```